# Heroku Node.JS Website - href attribute not working in HTML?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, server-side

I have uploaded a site to heroku and when I use the href tag to redirect to another page it doesn't seem to work.

I was able to do localhost:1000/other.html, that works but when it comes to href="/other" with a 'a' tag; it doesn't work.

In my server script I put the following to make it work:

```js
const app = express();

app.use('/static', express.static('public'))

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
    console.log("we in /");
});

app.get('/other', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './other.html'));
    console.log("we in other.html");
});
```

My tag contains:

```html
<a href="/other">
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't a very useful description of the problem. What happens when you click on the link? Does the URL in the browser's address bar change? Does anything get reported in the Network tab of the browser's developer tools (make sure you have **Preserve log** selected so it doesn't clear when navigating to a new page).

Comment: Does the `console.log` statement log anything on the server side? What happens if you visit `/other` *directly* without clicking a link?

Comment: Your tag seems to be missing any content and its matching `</a>`. You should make sure your [mcve] is complete.

Comment: `localhost:1000/other.html` **shouldn't** work: You have no handler for it. While your static handler *might* be able to pick up `http://localhost:1000/static/other.html` the URL you said worked is missing the `/static` part.

Comment: Does the URL in the browser's address bar change? No, it remains the same. Does anything get reported in the Network tab of the browser's developer tools? It doesn't appear to be changing at all. The console.log works on the server side, it prints "we in /" when rendering into index.html  What happens if you visit /other directly without clicking a link? It only doesn't work when clicking the href attribute is when it doesn't work.